# Highcharts yAxis click event

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to render some data. On the yAxis I needed those values to be anchor tags and navigate to a side modal.  Was able to get that working correctly by using the formatter function of the labels object.  What I am trying to do now is the first cell of the table I want to disable the click events so it does not take the user to the side modal its display only.

```
labels{
 align: 'left',
 formatter: function(){
  return `<a href=javascript:openModal() ${this.value}  </a>`
 }
}
```

I've tried with jquery targeting the first table cell like

```
$('tspan.highcharts-anchor:first').unbind();
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like in this demo? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25c38ez4/

Comment: that worked for me thanks can put it as the answer and will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments - there is a code which disables opening the modal on the first yAxis.label.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25c38ez4/

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        console.log(this)
        if (this.isFirst) {
          return this.value
        } else {
          return `<a href=javascript:openModal()> ${this.value} </a>`
        }

      }
    }
  }
```