# Highcharts yAxis labels click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So couple weeks ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939126/highcharts-yaxis-click-event) on how to access the click event of HighCharts yAxis.  I was greatly helped out but an example of using `formatter:function(){somecode}`. Initially this did work but I have multiple high charts on a page and for some odd reason it throws off the css of the highcharts plot options tooltip/overlay.  I have researched the documentation and the chart itself has a event click that works but is there anything else that works on the yAxis?

I've just tried to access the tspan and add a click event listener just nothing is happening.  Any other suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `custom_events` plugin and add the event in this way:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xnr7hqap/

**Docs:** https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/